# Join navigation property with line

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I try to join a navigation property by using LINQ.
This is my code

```
    var activities = Using<GetActivitiesForUser>()
        .Execute(User.DisplayAs, User.MarketId);

    var contacts = Using<GetContactsForUser>()
        .Execute(User.DisplayAs, User.MarketId);

    var model = from activity in activities
                join contact in contacts
                on activity.ContactId equals contact.ContactId
                select activity;
```

This code will only select the activity without any join.
The activity has a property named Contact, and i want to join that property from Contacts.

**UPDATE**

Example to solve it

```
foreach(var activity in activities)
{
activity = from contact in contacts
where contact.ContactId=activity.ContactId
select contact
}
```

But i want to do this with a join.

Comment: What do you want the result of the query to be?

Comment: What is in this `Using` method?

Comment: The Using method is for calling my services layer to get data. Its a custom method and have nothing to to with the join i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include both activities and contacts in the query result:

```cs
from activity in activities
join contact in contacts
on activity.ContactId equals contact.ContactId
select new { activity, contact };
```

or select individual properties of both objects.

**Edit** After your comment:

You won't be able to let Dapper populate activity.contact, it is deliberately kept simple. What you can do is loop through the results and set the property yourself:

```cs
foreach(var anon in model)
{
    anon.activity.contact = anon.contact;
}
```

where model is the query `.ToList()`.

Another effective, but ugly way could be:

```cs
model.Select(x => { x.activity.contact = x.contact; return activity; }).ToList();
```

Which immediately returns the modified activities. It is ugly because it abuses a method that is intended to be stateless (`Select`), but yeah...

Comment: Doesnt help. I need to do activity.contact = contact

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Entity Framework

try

```
var model = activities.Include("Contact");
```

Comment: Sorry, i use dapper so lazy loading is not an option.